# Particle Sprites are slightly accumulating pixels where alpha is 0%

Tags: ios, opengl-es, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am rendering particles with a Vertex and Fragment shader.

In my vertex shader I am clamping the alpha component of the output fragment color:

```
highp float alpha = clamp(rotatedTexture.a, 0.01, 0.05);
highp vec4 base = vec4(vShade.r, vShade.g, vShade.b, alpha);
fragmentColor = base;
```

The value for rotatedTexture.a is read in from the following PNG - I have made absolutely sure that there are no edges in the bitmap - anything that resembles a square should not be drawn.

[image]

But, you can see squares rendered - even though the effect is slight - they are definitely there. I highlighted one sprite with a black border (two good examples are a large green and pink sprite overlapping each other in the lower right corner).

Since I am clamping the alpha to 5% percent, and since there are clearly no hard edges with my texture's alpha - how can it possibly be drawing hard edges? Note that I am seeing the same thing with different textures.

[image]

Comment: The geometry itself has a hard edge. If you don't have an alpha which is actually zero (which you don't because of the > 0.0 minimum on the clamp), then you're going to get some amount of the quad visible.

Why is your clamp min value higher than zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Whatever your texture alpha is, your clamp function returns 0.1 to 0.5 because you set so.

If your texture alpha is zero, your clamp function returns 0.1 or

if your texture alpha is over 0.5, it returns 0.5

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is where the dark border is coming from.

Comment: @solidpixel Isn't that what he highlighted in person? he said "I highlighted one sprite with a black border"

Comment: @solidpixel and read the title "Particle Sprites are slightly accumulating pixels where alpha is 0%"